# grub boot loder gone, have aceess to only Windows boot, how to fix it?

Tags: windows-10, boot, debian, multi-boot, grub2

For reasons unknown, the grub2 bootloader doesn't load at all although the windows boot loader loads. You can see how the windows partition manager shows the linux partitions but is unable to show grub and hence debian, the OS I use primarily. I remember vaguely a way to install grub to a usb disk, install grub to the boot sector again and live happily every after. Can somebody share the instructions. I did share something on similar lines about a year ago but that was a different question altogether [thumbrules for figuring out space so that windows boot loader and linux can live happily.](https://superuser.com/questions/1285802/thumbrules-for-figuring-out-space-so-that-windows-boot-loader-and-linux-can-live)

Here is a screenshot of the hdd as it looks under Ms-Windows 10 as of now.

[image: windows in-build partition manager]

Most of the partitions makeup can be seen here, although am not aware of couple of partitions as to what they are about.

[image: disk-internals-linux]
 I sadly don't remember what the other partitions are for, one of it is probably is for all my media or extraneous stuff etc.

Looking forward to know what would be the best way forward.

Comment: Open UEFI settings and select Debian (Grub) again.

Comment: there is no Debian (Grub) in UEFI settings unfortunately :(

Comment: If there isn't then something or someone deleted from the ESP or if still there then a firmware update may have reset the UEFI. Or Debian was installed in Legacy... Except this last one the other possibilities should be fixable from a live session.